# Why can't I parse this data- value?

Tags: jquery, json

I have an html link that has a `data-` element on it:

```
<a data-drink-size="R" class="editItem">Edit</a>
```

I have a click function bound to it (which does get called; that's not an issue) where I'm trying to pass the value of `data-drink-size` into an ajax call. I've logged out the value of the element, but it's an object, and I can't seem to parse it correctly to return just the value. Here's what I have:

```
console.log($(this).data());
var drink_size = $(this).data("drink_size")
console.log("drink unparsed: " + drink_size);
console.log("drink parsed: " + jQuery.parseJSON(drink_size));
```

Here's what I get back from Firebug for those lines:

[image]

What do I need to do to get just the `R` back from `$(this).data("drink_size")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong selector of your attribute because in your html is `data-drink-size` and not `data-drink_size`. Try this:

```
var drink_size = $(this).data("drink-size");
```

Instead of:

```
var drink_size = $(this).data("drink_size");
```

Comment: Argh. Of course it would be something stupid like that. I could have stared at it for days and not realized that I had a typo in the selector. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your data attribute is `drink-size` and not `drink_size`

You need this

```
var drink_size = $(this).data("drink-size");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its just a typo. This should fix it :

```
var drink_size = $(this).data("drink-size");
```